# What role do I need to assign to my user to read and write to my CosmosDB container?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I connect to by database and try to read some data from a container, I get a 403 error that says my principal doesn't have Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata permission.

I have gone through all the roles available in the Azure portal, but none of them do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For some absolutely wild reason, the roles available in the UI are not enough to start reading data from Cosmos. Instead, you need to assign a special, hidden role that exists in the system to read or write data.

See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#metadata-requests

Specifically, it's the roles 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 for read and 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 for read+write. The same article has an explanation of how to add these from Azure Powershell:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#using-azure-powershell-1

I nearly lost my mind trying to figure out why I couldn't read my own data, given I had given several role kinds to my user, none of which worked. I have no idea why the Azure team decided to hide the required roles from the UI. Hopefully they see this answer and shed some light.